# How can i make the image change 3 times with only 1 button press?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, button

The button has to be pressed three times in order for the image to change three times. how can i make it so the button is only pressed once, yet it still changes the image three times?

```
<body>
 <h1>Traffic Light</h1>
<br>
 <img id="myImage" src="Traffic_green.png" width="100" height="400">
<br>
 <button type="button" onclick="changeImage()">Traffic light</button> //when clicked it runs function changeImage()
<br>
 <p>Click to make the traffic light work</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function in your callback.. where 6 is the number of times to run, and 1000 is the delay between changes.. you can obviously change them as your requirement.

```js
function change3(){
    for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        setTimeout(changeImage, 1000*i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` to cycle through the other images after 1500ms (1.5 seconds):

```html
<body>
  <script>
    function changeImage() {
      var lightDelay = 1500;  // delay between lights
      var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
      if (image.src.match("Traffic_green")) {
        image.src = "Traffic_red.png";  // changes image from green to red traffic light
        setTimeout(function() {
          image.src = "Traffic_yellow.png";  // changes image from red to yellow traffic light

          setTimeout(function() {
            image.src = "Traffic_green.png";  //changes image from red to yellow traffic light
          }, lightDelay)
        }, lightDelay)
      }
    }
  </script>

  <h1>Traffic Light</h1>
  <br>
  <img id="myImage" src="Traffic_green.png" width="100" height="400">
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="changeImage()">Traffic light</button>//when clicked it runs function changeImage()
  <br>
  <p>Click to make the traffic light work</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, you want to be looking at [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout). I'd also use [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) so the timeouts don't stack up if you keep clicking the button. Try this:

```
<script>
  var timerId;
  function buttonClick() {
    var count = 0;

    // Cancel any currently running sequence
    if(timerId) {
      clearTimeout(timerId);
    }

    // Inner function to change after 3 secs and run again if needed
    function doChange() {
      timerId = setTimeout(function() {
        if(count++ < 3) {
          changeImage();
          doChange();
        }
      }, 3000);
    }

    // Start the sequence
    doChange();
  }

  function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (image.src.match("Traffic_green")) {
      image.src = "Traffic_red.png";  //changes image from green to red traffic light
    } else if (image.src.match("Traffic_red")) {
      image.src ="Traffic_yellow.png";  //changes image from red to yellow traffic light
    } else {
      image.src ="Traffic_green.png";  //changes image from red to yellow traffic light
    }
  } 
</script>


<body>
 <h1>Traffic Light</h1>
<br>
 <img id="myImage" src="Traffic_green.png" width="100" height="400" style="background-color: green">
<br>
 <button type="button" onclick="buttonClick()">Traffic light</button> //when clicked it runs function changeImage()
<br>
 <p>Click to make the traffic light work</p>
</body>
```